# How to hide empty custom tab in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, tabs

I have added the custom attribute tab on the product page. If the tab is empty is must be hidden.

> > I have created an attribute customtab.

I have added below code in the catalog_product_view.xml inside body tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="customtab.tab" template="Magento_Catalog::customtab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

How can I hide the custom attribute tab?

Comment: How have you added the tab ? Please update the question with code the code used so we can help you.

Comment: @Frank, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::product/view/details/custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Tab Title</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 4. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details/custom_tab.phtml

```
<?php $attributeCode = '<product_attribute_code>'; ?>
<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getData($attributeCode); ?>
```

**Note:**

Add your html code in "if" condition, if html data found in tab content then tab will be display on the product page.

Comment: Thanks, It is working fine as I want. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @Vinodkumar - Happy to help. Keep helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code with below code. Below code will display attribute in tab if its contain any content/data. (Note: I have used short_description attribute for your reference) Don't forget to remove/clear cache before test.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.custominfo" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Short Details</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>              
            </referenceBlock>
```

I hope above code will help you.

Comment: According to your code (Magento Default Code), the tab will be shown if it does not contain any data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be like you need to add your own custom block class. I'd imagine that the answer provided by Nits wont work for a custom product attribute because nothing does.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\CustomAttributes" name="customtab.tab" template="Magento_Catalog::customtab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Take a look at `public/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/Review.php` as a reference. You will be able to create a method that will use the registry to get the current `$product` and find out whether your value / values are set. You will then be able to override the toHtml method to output nothing or you can set the `setTabTitle()` to nothing if not set.